# Azure Load Balancer probe endpoint and Keep-Alive header

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-traffic-manager

I have a custom load balancer probe endpoint for an Azure Service that hosts an ASP.NET application. I'm wondering whether Keep-Alive response header would have any effect on behavior of the Azure Load Balancer and Traffic Manager caused by persisted connections.

Answer (score 1):

No, that header will not impact either the Azure LB or Azure Traffic Manager.  The Keep-Alive header is a suggestion to the client that it should keep the connection alive, but there is no requirement on the client side to do so.  Azure LB and ATM will ignore that header.